# How to insert returning data from stored procedure to a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure with parameters and the returning result is a single row with columns. I need to insert that row to a table.i wanna use that result inside of an another stored procedure. How can i do that ? My result is below :

```
ID |  TotalTime  |  DeservedTime
25 |    100      |      150
```

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Which database system do you use?

Comment: i use microsoft sql server,t-sql

Comment: you should try `select into` to insert the SP results into your table..and then `select top 1 * From your_backup_table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can insert exec

```
insert into SomeTable
exec yourStoredProcedure
```

SomeTable should match the returning schema of yourStoredProcedure

Comment: thank you so much :) i did it as you said. i will add a test code as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE PROC erdemtest
    @param1 int,
    @param2 int
as
    select @param1,@param2  


    example : 

declare @tbl table( param1 int,param2 int)

insert into @tbl
exec erdemtest 1,2
select SUM(param1+param2) from @tbl


result is :

3
```